# Android Recyclerview on Filter EditText stay on same place

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hello Someone please help me with this,

[image]

You can see above GIF image, Here i have a recyclerview with data and each item in recyclerview has a Edittext where user can enter quantity, but the problem i m facing here is whenever user filter the list by using search filter as you can see in above Gif, the user entered quantity in EditText box remains in same place

Comment: please also include your code

Comment: I Got the Solution bro, I was not update the recyclerview List Item item wise in OnBindView

Comment: Can you till me 

I have DataModel and ArrayList<SaleDatamodel> dataSet; 

I want to Update this ArrayList<SaleDatamodel>

I Tried using doing like this 

dataSet.set(listPosition," Here it saying Required SalesDatamodel ").setSalesQuantity("10");

Comment: `clear` your list first then use `addAll`